# How can I efficiently extract text from a PDF with many objects

Tags: python, pdf, memory, text-extraction, pdfminer

I am using PDFMiner.Six to extract text from many PDF's. I Noticed that a few PDF's take much longer and some take so long that I end up killing the program. These PDF's can have up to 136,000 objects causing the script to use up to 20 GB of memory. I did not have this issue when using PyMuPDF but I can no longer use that library so I switched to PDFMiner.six. I can't use PyPDF because I need to extract text from a certain location using bounding boxes.

Below I have the 2 implementations of extracting text. The first method I try to extract text from a certain location but the script slows down when I try to loop through text_page at the start.

```
for LTGen in text_page:
        print('LTGen', LTGen)
        for LTPage in LTGen:
            if isinstance(LTPage, Iterable):
                for LTLine in LTPage:

                    if hasattr(LTLine, 'get_text'):
                        temp = {}
                        text = (LTLine.get_text()).strip()

                        if (len(text)>1 or isinstance(text,int)) and check_bbox(LTLine.bbox, p0, p1):
                            temp.update( {"text":text, 'bbox':LTLine.bbox} )

                            if isinstance(LTLine, Iterable):
                                for LTChar in LTLine:

                                    if hasattr(LTChar, 'fontname') and hasattr(LTChar, 'size'):
                                        temp.update( {"font":LTChar.fontname,  "size":int(LTChar.size)} )
                                        # print(temp)
                                        if not check_duplicate(temp, bbox_found):
                                            possible_values.append(temp)
```

This was my second method and the script slows down when I try to process the page.

```
fp = open(fileMetadata['fullPath'], 'rb')


    # STACKOVERFLOW SOLUTION
    #Create resource manager
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    # Set parameters for analysis.
    laparams = LAParams()
    # Create a PDF page aggregator object.
    device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, pageno=1, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp=fp, pagenos=[0], maxpages=0)

    for page in pages:
        
        print('Processing next page...')
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        # receive the LTPage object for the page.
        layout = device.get_result()

        for lobj in layout:
            if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox):
                print('FOUND LTTextBox')
                x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
                print('At %r is text: %s' % ((x, y), text))
```

What can I do to speed things up and not cause the text extraction to use up so much memory for PDF's that have many objects in the file?

Comment: @KJ Yes the text is always in the first page. Even if the amount of pages are more than 1. But in this case the pdf is only 1 page. There is an object in the middle that is highly populated with text and sag lines.

Comment: Maybe you might want to give pypdfium2 a try? `textpage.get_text_bounded()`